# Uncaught TypeError: onPageChange is not a function for DataGrid in Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to add DataGrid to my application. With the below code table is rendering fine but on click next page icon, I'm getting error - react-dom.development.js:327 Uncaught TypeError: onPageChange is not a function.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong here.

```
      <DataGrid rows={this.props.rowsData} 
                columns={this.props.columnsData} 
                sortModel={[
                  {
                    field: 'id',**strong text**
                    sort: 'asc',
                  },
                ]}
                pagination
                pageSize={5}
                rowCount={100}
                paginationMode="server"
                onPageChange={(params) => {
                  console.log("===params===",params);
                }}
                loading={this.state.loading}
                />
```

Below is the details of row data passed as props

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "columnNameA": "My Project 1",
        "columnNameB": null,
        "columnNameC": 65.9,
        "columnNameD": 5,
        "columnNameE": 387,
        "columnNameF": 0,
        "columnNameG": null
  },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "columnNameA": "My Project 2",
        "columnNameB": null,
        "columnNameC": 83,
        "columnNameD": 0,
        "columnNameE": 6,
        "columnNameF": 0,
        "columnNameG": null 
  }
]
```

Below is details of column data passed as props

```
[
    {
        "field": "id",
        "headerName": "Sl No",
        "width": 100,
        "headerClassName": "reportTable-col-header",
        "title": "Sl No"  
  },
    {
        "field": "columnNameA",
        "headerName": "First Column",
        "width": 300,
        "sortable": false,
        "headerClassName": "reportTable-col-header"  
  },
    {
        "field": "columnNameB",
        "headerName": "Second Column",
        "headerClassName": "reportTable-col-header",
        "width": 200,
        "resizable": true,
        "title": "Second Column"  
  },
    {
        "field": "columnNameC",
        "headerName": "Third Column",
        "headerClassName": "reportTable-col-header",
        "width": 200,
        "resizable": true,
        "title": "Third Column"  
  },
    {
        "field": "columnNameD",
        "headerName": "Fourth Column",
        "headerClassName": "reportTable-col-header",
        "width": 200,
        "resizable": true,
        "title": "Fourth Column"  
  },
    {
        "field": "columnNameE",
        "headerName": "Fifth Column",
        "headerClassName": "reportTable-col-header",
        "width": 200,
        "resizable": true,
        "title": "Fifth Column"  
  },
    {
        "field": "columnNameF",
        "headerName": "Sixth Column",
        "headerClassName": "reportTable-col-header",
        "width": 200,
        "resizable": true,
        "title": "Sixth Column"  
  },
    {
        "field": "columnNameG",
        "headerName": "Seventh Column",
        "headerClassName": "reportTable-col-header",
        "width": 200,
        "resizable": true,
        "title": "Seventh Column"  
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you provide this.props.rowsData and this.props.columnsData? I can use onPageChange() with my own data just fine.

Comment: @Viet I updated the question please verify and let me know.

Comment: Updated in the sandbox, still fine. Check my sandbox in answer below

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Material UI 4, then try using

```
onChangePage={(params) => {
              console.log("===params===",params);
            }}
```

rather than

```
onPageChange={(params) => {
              console.log("===params===",params);
            }}
```

Notice the slight difference in name. Even though its stated that onChangePage is deprecated, it may just be a versioning issue and will work in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Check how you define your rowsData and columnsData. I made a working sample with same code for DataGrid, I used my own rows and columns data and I can call onPageChange() just fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-panini-975sd?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I'm using the class component and trying something like this - https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-meadow-embvh

Comment: I can clearly see the console.log for params when click next page in your sandbox ...

Comment: Didn't updated the version before, here it is - https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-meadow-embvh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I got it now!! clearly it is a version issue. I'll change the versions in my dependencies. Thanks for your time!!

Comment: Glad I could help :)